# how to block the scrollTo animation on click

Tags: jquery

How to prevent the scrollTo animation in on click event,

```
jQuery.scrollTo.window().queue([]).stop();
```

This code is not working for me

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something for you in jQuery.

with my first function i trigger the scrolling top animation. In the second one i check if the user clicked anywhere on the page (except the scroll to top button) and stopped the animation.

```
$(document).on("click", ".scroll", function(){
    $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 5000);
    return false;
});

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    var page = $("html, body");
    if (e.target !== $(".scroll")) {
       page.on("click", function(){
           page.stop();
       });  
    }
    return false;
});
```

Here i did a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/we99f20n/2/